How to implement Enum with mutable members, comparable and hashable by their index
I am writing a class to represent sequential stages of an industrial process, composed of ADMISSION, PROCESSING, QC and DELIVERY stages.
Each stage has a unique, progressive sequence number, a mnemonic name and a field keeping track of the number of instances going through it:
@dataclass
class Stage:
    seq_id:       int
    name:         str
    n_instances:  int

Since stages are well-known and not supposed to change during execution, I decided to gather them in an Enum.
I need said enum to have the following requirements:
enum members need to:

be subclasses of Stage , in order to avoid accessing their value and making them easier to use (akin to IntEnum or StrEnum). In particular:

be comparable by their seq_id (e.g. Stages.DELIVERY > Stages.PROCESSING is true)

be usable as dictionary keys

use name as their __str__ representation.



have immutable, sequential seq_ids from 0 to n based on their declaration order

name is specified at member declaration. Using auto() results in the lower-cased member name


I managed to address point 2 and 3 in my implementation (see below).
How can I implement point 1 (and its subpoints)?
Final implementation
(fixed thanks to @EthanFurman's answer)
The idea is to use Stage instances as the enum members, and use their seq_ids as member values.

seq_id is no longer in the Stage class as it is stored directly
in the enum member's _value_; I made this choice because I deem
seq_ids not to have meaning outside the enum.

seq_id cannot be specified at member declaration. Instead, it is automatically generated based on declaration order (thanks to auto-numbering enum pattern). This prevents invalid seq_ids from being specified

dunder methods __lt__ , __eq__, __str__ and __hash__ have been implemented
inside the enum rather than the Stage class because their behavior is tied to the use of the enum members

Hashing is based on the member's _value_, which is supposedly
immutable (hashing Stage would've been tricky due to its
mutability)


@dataclass
class Stage:
    label:        str
    n_instances:  int = 0

@total_ordering         
class Stages(Stage, Enum): #req no. 1 (members are subclasses of stage)

    #req no. 1.1
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self.value < other.value
        return NotImplemented
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self.value == other.value
        return NotImplemented
    
    #req no. 1.2
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)

    #req no. 1.3
    def __str__(self):
        return self.label

    #req no. 2
    def __new__(cls, label):
        #auto numbering enum pattern for seq_ids
        value = len(cls.__members__) + 1

        obj = Stage.__new__(cls)

        #enum value set to seq_id
        obj._value_ = value

        return obj
    
    #req no. 3
    @override
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        return name.lower()

    ADMISSION = auto()
    PROCESSING = auto()
    QC = auto()
    DELIVERY = auto()

#ordering test     
assert(Stages.PROCESSING.__lt__(Stages.DELIVERY))

#dictionary key test
stage_to_color = {
    Stages.ADMISSION :  "#B10156",
    Stages.PROCESSING : "#F4B704",
    Stages.QC :         "#FD0002",
    Stages.DELIVERY :   "#7FB857"
}

assert(stage_to_color[Stages.QC] == "#FD0002")


This looks weird. How about storing n_instances elsewhere, for instance in a dictionary? That way you could have true immutable enums.

@Olivier I see your point, but then each time I have to make changes to the stages I'd have to edit both the Enum and the dictionary. The appeal of Enum is defining and accessing all these well known instances from one place.

"I'd have to edit both the Enum and the dictionary" Why would you have to edit the enum? An enum should be immutable.

@Olivier that would happen sporadically and not during execution e.g. management decides to add a "packaging" stage so I define it inside the enum, compile and release the new version

Both dataclass and Enum do a lot of work to make things simple for the user -- when you start extending and/or combining them you need to be careful.
Working code:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum, auto, unique
from functools import total_ordering
from typing import override

@dataclass
class Stage:

    seq_id:       int
    label:        str                         # name and value are reserved by Enum
    n_instances:  int = 0

    # req 1.2
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.seq_id)


@total_ordering             #req no. 1 (members are subclasses of stage)
class Stages(Stage, Enum):

    #req no. 1.1 (ordering)
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self.seq_id < other.seq_id
        return NotImplemented

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self.seq_id == other.seq_id
        return NotImplemented

    #req no. 1.3
    def __str__(self):
        return self.label

    #req nos. 2 & 3
    @override
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        return count, name.lower()

    ADMISSION = auto()
    PROCESSING = auto()
    QC = auto()
    DELIVERY = auto()


thank you for your answer! I have incorporated it inside the "My implementation" part of the question, with the difference that seq_id's are no longer accessible outside the enum and hashing is also handled by the enum

Python's Enum doesn’t support subclassing directly. Instead, you can create Stage instances as enum members and assign a unique seq_id to each one.

I believe my implementation already uses Stage instances as enum members and seq_ids as values. If I understood correctly, this is achieved by having Stages be a subclass of (Stage, Enum) and overriding __new__ so that it returns a Stage object having its _value_ field set to seq_id (as I did in my example)

Enum does support subclassing in many cases -- do you have a specific example where it does not?

I think there might be a misunderstanding. While Enum can be used with subclasses, mixing it with mutable classes or custom methods can be tricky. It’s usually simpler to use instances of your class (like Stage) as enum members with unique seq_id's. This approach avoids complications and keeps things straightforward.
